# JSON value is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I am still learning javascript and I need a little help.
I am getting the word undefined instead of my own string, can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code. Thanks in advance.

**My Code:**

```js
const logoData = [


  {
    name: "Arizona Cardinals",
    sport: "Football"
  },
  {
    name: "Atlanta Falcons",
    sport: "Football"
  }

];

document.getElementById("library").innerHTML = `
${logoData.map(function(logo) {
    return `
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${logoData.name}</h5>
  </div>
</div>
`
}).join('')}`
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!--Bootstrap style-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--Bootstrap scripts-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="library"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You made a typo. `function(logo)` names the variable `logo` but you said `${logoData.name}` instead of `${logo.name}`. (Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo).

Comment: Also: That's **JavaScript**, not JSON.

Comment: Also: no need to wrap the whole thing in a template string; `Array.join()` already returns a string.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Inside the `map` callback, the variable you want to use is called `logo`:

```
<h5 class="card-title">${logo.name}</h5>
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the block.

Comment: I agree that a question that boils down to a typo has no long term value (including this one). However, could it not also be possible that OP misunderstands how functions and variables work?